# Pascal - find if element exists in a set

Tags: pascal

I have got a code like this:

```
program Project1;
uses crt;
type alph=set of 'A'..'Z';
var mn:alph;

begin
  clrscr;
  if ('A' in mn) then writeln( 'Yes');
  readln;
end.
```

It doesn't print anything and it throws some issues :
***project1.lpr(11,14) Warning: Variable "mn" does not seem to be initialized***
I don't understand why, is there something wrong?

Comment: The error message means what it says.  Until you make an assignment to `mn` you should not assume it has any particular value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration

```
type
  Alpha = set of 'A'..'Z';
```

simply says that `Alpha` is a type that is allowed to contain zero or more of the letters between `A` and `Z` inclusive. It does not mean that a variable of that type automatically contains every element of that set; it simply means that the variable will consist of a set of characters within that range.

```
var
  mn: Alpha;                // Uninitialized variable that can contain 
                            // characters between 'A'..'Z'.
begin
  mn := ['A'..'Z'];         // Valid set of every member
  mn := ['A', 'C', 'X'];    // Valid set of three members
```

The compiler is correctly telling you that you have not assigned any value to `mn`, and therefore you're using an uninitialized variable.

BTW, the standard convention in most Pascal dialects is to preface types with a `T` to make it clear it's a type. So, with that in mind, here's a working version of the code you've posted with that correction included.

```
program Project1;

uses 
  crt;

type 
  TAlpha=set of 'A'..'Z';

var 
  mn: TAlpha;
begin
  clrscr;
  mn := ['A'..'Z'];
  if ('A' in mn) then
    Writeln('A is in mn');
  {
    My preference to the if statement above - prints true or false
    depending on whether the character is in the set, so you get output
    either way.
  }
  WriteLn('A in mn: ', ('A' in mn));
  Readln;
end.
```

To address your additional question (from the comment below):

To check a string to see if all characters are numeric ('0'..'9'), you can do something like this:

```
function IsNumeric(const str: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for i := 1 to Length(str) do
    if not (str[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
      Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: Nice code ..and what if I had a string which consists of random characters f.e. it can be "a2es0" and I need to check whether this string contains only numbers(would return False for this string) and I want to make it with **in** operator so something like 
`    for i:=1 to 5 do begin
         if not(str[i] in ['0'..'9'] then do something ....  
`
Could I run it?

Comment: Yes, you could run that. You could have also tried it yourself to find out, you know? :-) Better would be `for i := 1 to Length(str) do begin if str[i] not in ['0'..'9'] then DoSomething; end;`.

Comment: @Ken:  Don't you mean `if not (str[i] in ['0'..'9'])`?  +1 for good answer btw.

Comment: @Martyn: Yes,. :-) I would have written it that way in an answer.  Updated post to address the issue and correct that example. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing wrong so far. However, as the warning says, `nm` is not initialized. You will either run into undefined behaviour (I'm not sure whether this is actuall possible in Pascal) or the code snippet does nothing useful - you wish to check whether `mn` contains `'A'`, but have not put anything into into `mn`.

Comment: Well I thought that mm will be something like array filled with values from a to z...how do I check if a char is from alphabet then? Thanks